# SQL Server pivot table with case statement

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have created a PIVOT table and it works fine when averaging the results:

```
)AS PivotTable PIVOT( AVG( Score )FOR KPIID IN( [153],[2],[25],[48] ))AS PivotedTable
```

However, we have a table that specifies the type of grouping for each item, so i need something like this:

```
)AS PivotTable PIVOT( CASE KPIDirection WHEN 1 THEN AVG( Score ) WHEN 2 THEN SUM(Score) END FOR KPIID IN( [153],[2],[25],[48] ))AS PivotedTable
```

But this results in a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Any ideas?

[UPDATE] - FULL QUERY:

```
SELECT *
  FROM( 
        SELECT ISNULL( Users_KPIs_Daily.UserScore , 0 )AS Score , 
               u.UserID AS UserID , 
               KPIs.KPIID AS KPIID
          FROM KPIs
               LEFT OUTER JOIN Users_KPIs ON KPIs.KPIID = Users_KPIs.KPIID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN Users AS u ON u.UserID = Users_KPIs.UserID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN Users_KPIs_Daily ON Users_KPIs_Daily.UserID = Users_KPIs.UserID
                                               AND Users_KPIs.KPIID = Users_KPIs_Daily.KPIID )AS PivotTable1 

PIVOT( AVG( Score )FOR KPIID IN( [153] , [2] , [25] ,[48] ))AS PivotedTable1
```

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be... But to make sure i tried it like you said: still the same error.

Comment: " )AS PivotTable PIVOT( CASE WHEN KPIDirection = 1 THEN AVG( Score ) WHEN 2 THEN SUM(Score) END FOR KPIID IN( [153],[2],[25],[48] ))AS PivotedTable "

Comment: Could you post the entire code? Is `KPIDirection` available inside the PIVOT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for this problem, by moving the grouping inside the main table. So the AVG(Score) in the PIVOT table actually doesn't do anything, since the records are already grouped inside the main table.
I hope this helps someone:

```
SELECT *
  FROM( 
        SELECT CASE DailyKPIGrouping
               WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL( ROUND( AVG( Users_KPIs_Daily.UserScore ) , 2 ) , 0 )
               WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL( SUM( Users_KPIs_Daily.UserScore ) , 0 )
                   ELSE ROUND( SUM( ISNULL( Users_KPIs_Daily.UserScore , 0 ) * ISNULL( Users_KPIs_Daily.CustomData1 , 0 )) / CASE SUM( ISNULL( Users_KPIs_Daily.CustomData1 , 0 ))
                                                                                                                             WHEN 0 THEN 1
                                                                                                                                 ELSE SUM( ISNULL( Users_KPIs_Daily.CustomData1 , 0 ))
                                                                                                                             END , 2 )
               END AS Score , 
               u.UserID AS UserID , 
               KPIs.KPIID AS KPIID
          FROM KPIs JOIN Users_KPIs ON KPIs.KPIID = Users_KPIs.KPIID
                    JOIN Users AS u ON u.UserID = Users_KPIs.UserID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users_KPIs_Daily ON Users_KPIs_Daily.UserID = Users_KPIs.UserID
                                                    AND Users_KPIs.KPIID = Users_KPIs_Daily.KPIID
          GROUP BY KPIs.KPIID , 
                   u.UserID , 
                   DailyKPIGrouping )AS PivotTable1 
PIVOT( AVG( Score )FOR KPIID IN(153] ,[2] , [25] , [41] , [44] ))AS PivotedTable1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
)AS PivotTable PIVOT( CASE WHEN KPIDirection = 1 THEN AVG( Score )
                       WHEN KPIDirection = 2 THEN SUM(Score) END 
                FOR KPIID IN( [153],[2],[25],[48] )
```

) AS PivotedTable

Please replace above  line with old one... 
Then also, problem still remains then Show little bit of code..

Comment: Keeps displaying the same error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.